# What structure to implement for a document based app on react native

Tags: react-native, api

I’m a newbie to the programming world,
I’m building an app on react native for iOS and Android
The objective of the app is to give subscribers access to different pdf/word documents.

My question is to understand what structure is to be implemented for an efficient app. The question is ?
Should I develop an api which gives me The ability to upload documents and subscribers to the app can ‘Download’ PDFs. Should I use Google drive api or develop my own?

Or is there any other more efficient way to achieve the objective.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readme) if your application includes the document read, download, and upload(to any URL). If you'll use Google Drive you'll be relying too much on Google services, but this package allows you to add custom operations.

**Edit**

You can use [downloadFile](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#downloadfileoptions-downloadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promisedownloadresult-) for downloading a file from URL and [uploadFiles](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#uploadfilesoptions-uploadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promiseuploadresult-) for uploading.

Comment: Sorry for another newbie question! So that library plus allow me to create an api or it is has nothing to do with an api system?   Because basically I want my subscribers to be able to download the view/documents

Comment: Yes you can this package for any file-related operations like view and download documents from an API.